# Cocos2D animation - cut scene into pieces

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, split, scene

I found this animation http://youtube.com/watch?v=wt6gsIcNBOA (have a look at 1:46).
I can not find anything how this animation was accomplished. Basically it should look like the scene is cut into 3 different parts.

Any idea how to make a similar animation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its a "simple" CCTransitionSplitRows animation

```
CCTransitionSplitRows *transition = [CCTransitionSplitRows transitionWithDuration:1 scene:scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:transition];
```

there are more of such fancy transition in cocos2d
see
http://www.pawapps.com/2011/07/30/tutorial-transitions-in-cocos2d/ for example